# What is the probability that the two-seed makes the finals?

Tags: probability, contest-math

I can solve the following problem using brute-force combinatorics, but I'm looking for an elegant way to think about it, since there is a rather elegant answer.

> Suppose there is a tournament of $2^n$ seeded players. The initial bracket is chosen randomly, but thereafter each match is determined strictly by the rule that the higher seed advances. What is the probability that the player seeded number 2 makes it to the finals?

The answer is

$$\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$$

which can be obtained by counting the number of ways to arrange the players so that seeds 1 and 2 are in different halves of the bracket. However, a lot of really nice canceling happens in this method to give the rather elegant answer I've written above, so I'm guessing there is a better way to think about this problem. Is there some probability problem that is equivalent to this problem but is easier to think about? Or perhaps there is just an easier way to approach this problem than the way I have.

Answer (score 2):

We can imagine splitting the bracket into two halves, call them the left and right brackets. The winner of the left bracket and the winner of the right bracket go to the finals. Supposing without a loss of generality that the second seed is in the left bracket, the chances of that player making it to the finals are the same as the chances that the first seed (the only player who can beat the second seed) is in the right bracket. So placing the second seed in the left bracket leaves $2^n - 1$ spots left, and there are $2^{n-1}$ spots in the right bracket (half of the total number of spots). Thus we get $\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$.

Comment: Already answered above right?

Comment: @AndyRock I was already a good part of the way through writing it when the answers came in. I thought I would go ahead and submit. Although the math is basically the same, I think the explanation is different enough to leave this answer. OP and other users can decide which answer they like the most.

Comment: Well, I actually liked your explanation better.

Comment: @AndyRock Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try this way - This is kind of a heap sort.

The first player wins. There are $2^n-1$ players left. Out of them, If seed 2 is in the half of seed 1, he loses. Else, he wins. In each half, before coming to finals, there are $2^{n-1}$ players. So, he should be in one of the *other* $2^{n-1}$ players.

Thus, $2^{n-1}\over 2^n-1$